# Converting csv formatted hdfs files to Mahout vector files

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, mahout

I have comma separated data in hdfs, I would like to convert this into vectors to use with Mahouts Kmeans. There are flags in mahout `seqdirectory` and `seq2sparse` that converts data in a directory to vectors. The example given is for text files. Is there an equivalent flag for csv or is there a tutorial on how to create such files?